# NSDateComponentsFormatter Units Separator

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdatecomponentsformatter

I want to convert time in minutes to user friendly string. Following code resolves the issue, except one thing - I want result to look like `1 hr 30 min`, however I got `1 hr, 30 min`. How to specify units separator for NSDateComponentsFormatter? Of course, I can remove all commas manually, but it isn't looks like the best way for me.

```
    NSDateComponentsFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateComponentsFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.allowedUnits = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitHour | NSCalendarUnitMinute;
    formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleShort;

    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromTimeInterval:90*60]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application is targeting OS X 10.12 (or later, I presume) or iOS 10.10 (or later), then Apple added a new units style called "NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleBrief"

```
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleBrief
```

and it will print out "1 hr 30 min"

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatecomponentsformatterunitsstyle/nsdatecomponentsformatterunitsstylebrief?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line of code  `formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleShort;`

with

```
formatter.unitsStyle = NSDateComponentsFormatterUnitsStyleAbbreviated;
```

It is work according your requirement. I check in my xcode project.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer but I need 1 hr 30 min, however you code produces 1h 30m. I still need short description.

Comment: Ok i understand your requirement.

Comment: Mate you can use stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString. if you want result only for show on viewController.